# Ubuntu 17.10 - fails to pick up bluetooth devices after upgrading

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, 17.10

After upgrading my Kubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10, it cannot pick up any bt devices anymore.

I try to bt my bt keyboard, bt mouse, bt speaker, and android phone. None of them being displayed on the window below:

[image]

I tried:

`$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

I get:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [8086:15b7] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [8086:2064]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:9010]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: A0:C5:89:53:76:62  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
        RX bytes:29930 acl:0 sco:0 events:362 errors:0
        TX bytes:5214 acl:0 sco:0 commands:74 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'Bluemoon Universal Bluetooth Host Controller'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
        HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x100
        LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x100
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)

[    0.114205] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.602781] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    2.341734] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.341744] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.341746] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.341748] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.341752] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.349179] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.349180] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.349181] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.349194] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.349194] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.349195] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.349212] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.349224] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    2.349224] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    2.349225] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    2.349225] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    2.352194] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 118 week 50 2016
[    2.417815] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.417946] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.421670] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.532993.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.523935] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.523936] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.523938] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.595293] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    4.595298] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.595301] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   29.148960] Bluetooth: Failed to disable LE scan: status 0x0c
```

Any ideas what is going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced this issue on Ubuntu 17.10 with kernel 4.13.0-16-generic.

I have Bluetooth adapter "8087:0a2b Intel Corp.," and I receive the same error in your output:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i Blue

Ubuntu Bluetooth 8087 0a2b Intel Failed to disable LE scan status 0x0c
```

Here is a workaround that resolved the issue for me.

1. Edit `iwlwifi.conf`

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
   ```
2. Add the following line to the end of this file and save:

   ```
   options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
   ```
3. Then reboot.

This may be a regression kernel 4.13, per [Bug #1729389](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1729389). If you think  this bug affects you, you should mark yourself as impacted, so it gets addressed.

An alternative solution, suggested in the same bug report, may be to downgrade to kernel 4.10, but the above is probably easier to try first.

Comment: @laukok, Don't forget to register yourself on Launchpad and indicate that you are impacted by bug 1729389.  There are only three people who have done this (although I am sure many more are experiencing this issue!).  If enough people don't indicate that they are interested, the bug may never get prioritized, and the above work-around could stop working in a future release. Also, the above is a hack, so I don't know if there are any unwanted consequences; it would be nice to see a proper fix implemented.

Comment: How do register on launchpad?

Comment: Go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/.  Click on the "Log in / Register" link at the top right of the page.

After registering and logging in, go to the bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1729389.

Click on the green "This bug affects 2 people. Does this bug affect you?" link below the title of the bug. From the popup, select "Yes, it affects me".